# error: The element type 'Iterable<DataRow>' can't be assigned to the list type 'DataRow'

Tags: arrays, dictionary, object, flutter, dart

In the below code, I tried putting objects in another local list but it still didn't work:

```
class Amortization extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;
  final List<Installment> installments;

  Amortization({Key key, this.value, this.installments}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AmortizationState createState() => _AmortizationState();
}

class _AmortizationState extends State<Amortization> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(27, 202, 155, 2),
          title: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              "Amortization Schedule",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(25, 0, 64, 2),
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: DataTable(
                columns: <DataColumn>[
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Month"),),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Payment")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Principal")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Interest")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Total I")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Balance")),
                ],
                rows: <DataRow>[
                  widget.installments.map((Installment) => DataRow())
                ]
            )
    )
    );
  }
}
```

I'm seeing an error of

```
error: The element type 'Iterable<DataRow>' can't be assigned to the list type 'DataRow'
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Spread Operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) as shown below.

```dart
  rows: <DataRow>[
      ...widget.installments.map((Installment) => DataRow())
  ]
```

or use the `toList()` method:

```dart
  rows: widget.installments.map((Installment) => DataRow()).toList<DataRow>()
```

Comment: I just created a codepen version for the spread operator. Check it out [here](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/vYLXEee).

Comment: thanks @AbhilashChandran spent hours trying to find a way, youre a life saver but i wonder why there isnt an easier way of this implementation of datatables